# uart interfacing to RS422

Tags: uart

I am making a system which accepts signals (UART) from an external board. These signals are received by my MIcrocontrollers and further processed. Now, as part of the initial documentation I asked the client for the voltage levels of his boards as I did not know what voltage levels he would be sending (it could be coming 5V,3.3V or even very low voltage 1.8V based MCUs). As I did not know his MCUs I asked for a straightforward specifications of voltage(mainly the Voh,Vol, Vih and Vil). He sent me a document stating that my UART(in other words the UARTs in MCUs) should be TIA/EIA-422-b compliant.
The screenshot is as shown below -
[image: Screenshot]

Now, this is quite bizzare as TIA/EIA-422-b is a RS422 standard specification and RS422 is differential. So, I will need a UART to RS422 level shifter in between, right ?

Also, from the specs of RS422 I understand that they are +-10V signalling. Right ?

Comment: They are +/-2.5V differential.

Comment: thank you. But, is the screen shot that I shared and my ubnderstanding in sync ? I will be needing an UART to RS422 level shifter, right ?

Comment: Yes, you need a shifter and you must have proper transmission line. This is not always obvious.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič. How can you say +/-2.5. Some even have +/-2V(https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/723) and in this link (http://rs485.com/rs485spec.html), the receiver is +/-10V rated !!!!

Also, my UART will be only RS422 compliant in electrical specs, not in speed and being differential.

Comment: It can't be RS422 compliant if it's not differential, it has no sense. Newer devices have 5V supply and they povide 0 to 5V output signals biased at 2.5V, thats where +-2.5Vdiff comes from, and they can accept receive signal levels +-10V, they are rs422 compliant. Best solution is to buy a rs422/rs485 optoisolated transceiver module with dc/dc converter. Also RTS signal is ussualy needed to switch output tristate from HiZ to operation.

Comment: Something like this http://www.nyplatform.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=643

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you take a typical differential transceiver with the necessary protection and full compliance to the standards?

Here is the minimalistic option http://www.ti.com/product/ds8921